# How to save password in database - Firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, security, bcrypt

I have an App written by react-native and in back-end I used firebase,

and I have I sign-up screen with some fields and save it very well BUT I have a password field and i want to save it in DB to use it when the user wants to update his password or something,

SO, it's not a safe idea to save a password as a plaintext!

so how can I save passwords in the best safe way?

I think it's not a good idea to hash passwords on the client-side then save it into DB
 So what you think?

Answer (score 0):

You're correct that storing a password in plaintext is a bad idea, but storing a (salted) hash representation of a password is not. The benefits of hashing your password server-side vs. client-side is debatable and there's no strict answer; you'll have to weigh the pros and cons.

This question is a duplicate, and you can find far more detailed answers here:

- [Best way to store password in database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054022/best-way-to-store-password-in-database)